# Store filename to a Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a file upload code that automatically creates a folder for storing the files. Now I want to store every filename to a certain table. Btw, the table has an auto-increment column for file-id and img_link for the filename itself. This is the code I have written.

```
<?php
session_start();
$table_name = $_SESSION['un'];
if (!is_dir($table_name)) {
    mkdir($table_name);
}
$dir = $table_name . '/';
if (isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
    $ret = array();
    $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    {
        if (!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $dir . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
            $ret[$fileName] = $dir . $fileName;
        } else {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("mdrusr") or die(mysql_error());
            for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                echo $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                $ret[$fileName] = $dir . $fileName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $fileName);
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table_name (img_link) VALUES ('$fileName')", $connect);
            }

        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

but mysql_query part doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not help here. What is the exact error you get? What do the http server error log files say? What happens? We cannot help if you don't provide the details...

Comment: And stop using the old and long deprecated mysql extension. Use the one of the newer, recommended extensions instead.

Comment: echo "INSERT INTO $table_name (img_link) VALUES ('$fileName')"; check the connection

Comment: $table_name check this value also

Comment: and you're sure that `$table_name` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call seem wrong

```
mysql_query($connect, "INSERT INTO $table_name SET img_link='$fileName'");
```

$connect goes first

also not sure your query was valid sql

As I wrote it it should be correct.

Finally it is strongly reccomended to use **mysqli** instead of **mysql** set of php functions  (mysql ones are deprecated)

and

use prepared statements instead of injecting variables content directly into your queries.

For example: what happens if the filename contains a single quote? For example

**jenny's data.txt**

The query gets screwed up.

So to do thing in the right manner:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mdrusr"); // what about a password?
                                                              // note the db selection

if(!$connect) {...}

$query = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO ? SET img_link=?");
if(!$query)   {...}

$query->bind_param("ss", $table_name, $fileName);

$query->execute();

$query->close();

/* .... */

$connect->close();
```

Comment: +1 for actually reading OP's spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks Denis, but as the OP was complaining about the db code I just looked at that single line...

Comment: is this valid?  `INSERT INTO ? SET img_link=?`.... I've never seen an insert statement like that before.  OP's code says `"INSERT INTO $table_name (img_link) VALUES ('$fileName')"`, which is pretty valid if the table exists and the filename is escaped correctly.

Comment: yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html   for example: INSERT INTO foo SET bar = 1 WHERE biz > 3   note the question marks are not part of the sql syntax but placeholders for the prepared statement